# If $X_n\overset{d}\to 0$ and $a_n \to 0$, do we have $a_nX_n \overset{d}\to 0$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If $X_n$ converges to zero in distribution, do $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} X_n$ and $\frac{1}{n} X_n$ converge to zero in distribution? More generally, if $\lim a_n = 0$, do we have $a_n X_n \overset{d}\to 0$?

I set out to prove this but I got little confused on what is the cdf of zero. I am attempted to use Slutsky Theorem, but $a_n$ is not really a sequence of random variables?...

Comment: Isn't a constant only a special case of a random variable?

Comment: Hint. Forget about mathematics. There is no way it is going somewhere else. Now that you have faith, write down the definitions.

Comment: @GyroGearloose Umm... So I guess I just consider some $Z$ such that $Z(\omega) = 0$ for all $\omega\in\Omega$?

Comment: Given any $\epsilon>0$ if $P(|X|>\epsilon)\rightarrow0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, what happens to $P(|X/n|>\epsilon)$?

Comment: You can define functions $Y_n:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ prescribed by $\omega\mapsto a_n$. Then you can apply Slutsky on $Y_nX_n=a_nX_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X_n$ [converges to zero in distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_distribution) iff it [converges to zero in probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_probability).

If you want a proof of that then have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1791490/75923) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_convergence_of_random_variables#propB1).

So we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathsf P(|X_n|\geq\epsilon)=0$ for every $\epsilon>0$.

If $a_n\to0$ then eventually $\{|a_nX|\geq\epsilon\}\subseteq\{|X_n|\geq\epsilon\}$ so that $\mathsf P(|a_nX|\geq\epsilon)\leq\mathsf P(|X_n|\geq\epsilon)$.

So indeed we get: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathsf P(|a_nX_n|\geq\epsilon)=0$ for every $\epsilon>0$ and conclude that $a_nX_n$ converges to zero in distribution.

Answer (score 1):

This is a direct conclusion by applying [Slutsky's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem).

Comment: You're not addressing OP's concerns. He specifically mentioned that "$a_n$ is not really a sequence of random variables". You should add a few lines explaining why it is the case.